# How do I set up my mysql session to be in a certain timezone?

Tags: mysql

I need to dynamically change the timezone for mysql sessions due to traversing multiple databases which have different time zones.

How do I setup mysql to be tiemzone based for all mysql date related queries?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`SET TIME_ZONE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) to set your session to a specific UTC offset.

For example, I'm in UTC -05:00, but I can change to UTC like this:

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-03-02 12:32:39 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set time_zone = '+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-03-02 17:32:45 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: greate answer but how do we set in mysql confiq ??